# Why is my guard-rspec test failing?

Tags: ruby, rspec, guard

I set up my `guard-rspec` environment using the techniques described in [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/testing-your-ruby-code-with-guard-rspec-pry--cms-19974). I'm also practicing namespacing as described in [Programing Ruby](https://media.pragprog.com/titles/ruby3/ruby3_extract_packaging.pdf) starting on page 240. My current project directory is on [github](https://github.com/mbigras/phase-0-ruby-bulletin-board/tree/stack-overflow-post) in the `stack-overflow-post` branch.
I'm using:

```
❯ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin15.0]
❯ rbenv -v                                                            
rbenv 1.0.0
❯ rbenv versions                                                      
  system
* 2.1.1 (set by /Users/max/Google Drive/devbootcamp/phase-0-ruby-bulletin-board/.ruby-version)
  2.1.5
  2.2.3
  2.3.1
❯ bundle exec guard -v                                                
Guard version 2.3.0
```

I'm running a test in `spec/thread_spec.rb`:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'RubyBulletinBoard::Thread' do
    let (:thread) { RubyBulletinBoard::Thread.new }
    it { expect(thread).to be_kind_of(RubyBulletinBoard::Thread) }    

#     it 'has a valid uuid' do
#         p thread.uuid
#         expect(thread.uuid).to be_kind_of(String)
#     end

#     it 'has editable title' do
#         default_title = thread.title
#         thread.title = "#{default_title} something different"
#         new_title = thread.title
#         expect(default_title == new_title).to eq(false)
#     end    
end
```

However it's failing:

```
01:50:07 - INFO - Running: ./spec/thread_spec.rb:5
Run options: include {:locations=>{"./spec/thread_spec.rb"=>[5]}}

RubyBulletinBoard::Thread
  example at ./spec/thread_spec.rb:5 (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) RubyBulletinBoard::Thread
     Failure/Error: let (:thread) { RubyBulletinBoard::Thread.new }
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant RubyBulletinBoard::Thread
     # ./spec/thread_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/thread_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00055 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/thread_spec.rb:5 # RubyBulletinBoard::Thread

[1] guard(main)>
```

But I have no idea why because the class `RubyBulletinBoard::Thread` does exist in `lib/ruby_bulletin_board/thread.rb`:

```
require_relative 'id'

module RubyBulletinBoard
    class Thread
        attr_reader :uuid
        attr_accessor :title

        def initialize
           @uuid = IdCreator.create_id
           @title = title 
        end
    end
end
```

Even weirder, when I uncomment line 2 in `lib/ruby_bulletin_board/runner.rb` the test passes:

```
require_relative 'example'
# require_relative 'thread' # <--- THIS IS LINE 2

module RubyBulletinBoard
    class Runner
        attr_accessor :greeter, :thread

        def initialize
            @greeter = RSpecGreeter.new
            # @thread = RubyBulletinBoard::Thread.new
        end

        def run
            greeter.greet
            # p @thread.class
        end
    end
end
```

rspec output:

```
01:53:57 - INFO - Running: ./spec/thread_spec.rb:5
Run options: include {:locations=>{"./spec/thread_spec.rb"=>[5]}}

RubyBulletinBoard::Thread
  should be a kind of RubyBulletinBoard::Thread

Finished in 0.00114 seconds
1 example, 0 failures

[1] guard(main)>
```

It seems to me that including requiring `thread.rb` in `runner.rb` would have nothing to do with my tests.

1. Why is my original test in `spec/thread_spec.rb` failing?
2. Why does uncommenting line 2 in `lib/runner.rb` cause the test to pass?

Thanks for your help :)

**Edit:**

The accepted answer helped me get things up and running, more questions can be found in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37647524/questions-about-setting-up-a-working-guard-rspec-example-project)

**Edit 2:**
Also just made a big discovery: I've been using a file named `thread.rb`, there is a ruby class named Thread, so when I've been saying `require 'thread'` in my `thread_spec.rb` it's been giving me errors:

```
[1] guard(main)>
17:57:09 - INFO - Running: spec/thread_spec.rb
/Users/max/Google Drive/devbootcamp/phase-0-ruby-bulletin-board/spec/thread_spec.rb:4:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant RubyBulletinBoard (NameError)
    from /Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1361:in `load'
    from /Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1361:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1359:in `each'
    from /Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1359:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:106:in `setup'
    from /Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:92:in `run'
    from /Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:78:in `run'
    from /Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
    from /Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rspec:17:in `load'
    from bin/rspec:17:in `<main>'
17:57:10 - ERROR - Failed: "bin/rspec -f progress -r /Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-rspec-4.7.2/lib/guard/rspec_formatter.rb -f Guard::RSpecFormatter --failure-exit-code 2  spec/thread_spec.rb" (exit code: 1)
```

by renaming `thread.rb` -> `rbb_thread.rb` I can then `require 'rbb_thread'` and I'm going red to green :)

**Edit 3:**
Another solution for the errors with `thread.rb` is to `require_relative ../lib/thread` and so no rename is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things here:

1. When you're running specs, you're running RSpec like an application and it's "config" is in spec/spec_helper.rb. I'll assume it's empty/irrelevant.
2. If you're running a more recent version of RSpec, you can just place `--require spec_helper` in your `.rspec` file and you won't need the `require "spec_helper"` in your files.
3. It's best to use `RSpec.describe` instead of plain `describe` the first time in a file.
4. You can use a `subject` block for more readability along with `described_class`. It also lets you use `it { is.expected_to` syntax
5. `describe` can take a class name instead of a string. This way it makes it obvious if you've required the file or not. If you pass a class, then `subject` becomes implicit.

Since RSpec is like a separate app, it doesn't include your own library files by default (newer versions of RSpec do add `lib` to `LOAD_PATH`). So your tests have to individually require any files they test, e.g.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'RubyBulletinBoard::Thread' do
    let (:thread) { RubyBulletinBoard::Thread.new }
    it { expect(thread).to be_kind_of(RubyBulletinBoard::Thread) }
```

becomes:

```
require 'ruby_bulletin_board/thread'

RSpec.describe RubyBulletinBoard::Thread do
    it { is_expected.to be_kind_of(RubyBulletinBoard::Thread) }
```

If the above `require` fails, it means you need to put `lib` in your load path. Check your `spec/spec_helper.rb` if that's the case.

If your `spec/spec_helper.rb` is empty (or doesn't have anything important), you may want remove it along with `.rspec` and run `rspec --init` to generate a good started template for you. Be sure you uncomment the `=begin` and `=end` sections there.